# Can I give back nil instead of a tuple?

Tags: swift, tuples, vapor

My first version of code worked well:

```
return Question.find(o.questionId, on: req.db).map { q in
   guard let q = q else {
      return nil
   }
   return GetUserQuestionsOut(text: q.text, questionId: q.id!)
}
```

But if I work with tuples I got that 'nil' is incompatible with the return type:

```
return Question.find(o.questionId, on: req.db).map { q -> (String, GetUserQuestionsOut) in
guard let q = q else {
  return nil
} ...
```

Can I / How can I    give back nil instead of a tuple?

Comment: Better to use compactMap instead of map, then nil values will be excluded

Comment: Unfortunately "value of type 'EventLoopFuture<Question?>' has no member 'compactMap'".

Comment: Ah, I didn’t notice the vapor tag so I thought this was an ordinary swift collection

Comment: Creat a struct instead of a tuple and return it as Optional. This is the vaporous way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this,

```
... { q -> (String?, GetUserQuestionsOut?) in

  }
```

or

```
 ... { q -> (String, GetUserQuestionsOut)? in

  }
```

on the other hand, maybe you could consider using struct(model) or typealias instead of tuple